# Fisher information for exponential family: Regularity conditions

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, proof-writing, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

for the Fisher-Information to be defined certain regularity conditions have to be fulfilled (like in Lemma 5.3. in Theory of Point Estimation by E.L. Lehmann or on slide 2 here: http://www.stat.nus.edu.sg/~stachenz/40-530Statistics-6.pdf).

I know that any exponential family satisifies these conditions. But how does one formally show property (iv) on slide 2 in the last link for exponential families, i.e. that one can interchange derivative and integral/expectation? Should one use the dominated convergence theorem? And how does one prove the second assumption (ii) on slide 5 of the link? If you know literature containing the proof I am interested in reading it.

Looking forward to your answers!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that this follows from Theorem 5.8 in Theory of Point Estimation by Lehmann and Casella (1998, p.27):

> [image]

you can choose $\eta_i = \theta_i$ (the parameters of a distribution) in the abovementioned formula.

Answer (score -1):

To show both of the properties hold, you can use the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) which lets you pull the derivative inside the integral. Since, for the exponential family $p(x,\theta)$, the partial derivatives of $p(x,\theta)$ with respect to t exist, and is continuous.